# Retrieve StorageClass from S3 GetObject using AWSSDK

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We are evaluating the "Infrequent Access" storage option. I would like to know if an object is stored in STANDARD or STANDARD_IA when I retrieve an object, but the StorageClass is null in the GetObjectResponse object. Is there some way I can indicate that I want that populated in the response?
For us it makes sense to move an object to STANDARD if they request it once because they will likely touch it a few more times.

I did notice I can get this from ListObjects, but if I can get it at the time of the request, I would prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the SDKs because I work directly with the REST API... however, the REST API is the interface the SDKs use, so it's a reasonably safe assumption that an empty storage class in the response would be equivalent to `STANDARD`, because the API returns nothing for the storage class when that's the case.

> **x-amz-storage-class**
>
> Provides storage class information of the object. Amazon S3 returns this header for all objects except for Standard storage class objects.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

If this turns out to be an incorrect assumption, then examining the HTTP response headers (which I assume the SDK makes accessible) for the `x-amz-storage-class:` response header should get the answer, though again this header is completely absent for `STANDARD` objects.

This response header should also be accessible from a `HEAD` request'a response, and `HEAD`, would (I assume) be a method named something like `getObjectMetadata`.

Note that there is a small penalty for switching objects back from `STANDARD_IA` -- you pay for a retrieval fee, since this operation is actually a read followed by a write, moving data from one backing store to another within S3, and you pay for a minimum of 30 days of IA storage if the object has been in IA for less than 30 days when you change its class.

Comment: That was it. I didn't try any but Standard. The SDK does populate those properties when it is not Standard.